# Getting notified when a VPN connection disconnects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, core-foundation

How can I, within my Cocoa app, get a notification when the currently running VPN connection disconnects? I'm running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the System Configuration framework for this. You can examine the System Configuration hierarchy with [scutil(8)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html), and you might have a look at [HardwareGrowler's source code](http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Extras/HardwareGrowler) for examples of how to use the framework.

Also, documentation:

- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/
- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/